# Wait for every element in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I want to retrieve from a website every **div class='abcd'** element using Selenium together with 'waiter' and 'XPATH' classes from Explicit.
The source code is something like this:

```
<div class='abcd'>
   <a> Something </a>
</div>
<div class='abcd'>
   <a> Something else </a>
...
```

When I run the following code (Python) I get only 'Something' as a result. I'd like to iterate over every instance of the **div class='abcd'** appearing in the source code of the website.

```
from explicit import waiter, XPATH
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
result = waiter.find_element(driver, "//div[@class='abcd']/a", by=XPATH).text
```

Sorry if the explanation isn't too technical, I'm only starting with webscraping. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used like this. You can also use if you like this procedure.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

css_selector = "div.abcd"
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector))))

for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. So, in the "div.something" nomenclature, "something" is always the class? Is there any way to target another attribute of the HTML block? (like name, type, etc.)

Comment: Sure!. You can also use (id, name, xpath, link_text, partial_link_text, tag_name, class_name and css_selector) according to their official documentation. You can check here. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html